# Bootstrap-select plugin not working in partial view in asp.net core mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using a partial view using jquery's $.get() method but whenever I load the page the select element disappeared from the page. it shows in "Inspect element" section of a browser but I didn't see any error.

This error only occurs in partial views. If I load the page as View instead of Partial view then that plugin will work perfectly.

here is my code.
Please help if you know anything about this.

> NOTE:
> **Since partial view doesn't support @section so I have to put all the script elements in the beginning of the body tag so that all scripts from partial view will be register in dom after the _Layout page scripts. Otherwise I got the error like '$ is not defined' etc**

> This is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Website Name</title>
    <link rel=" shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/logo-icon.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/DataTables/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/customized-datatable.js"></script>


    <!--For font awesom 5.14.0 icons -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/font-awesome-5.14.0.js"></script>

    <!--Custom bootstrap modal-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/psychic-dev.js"></script>


    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ChangePassword")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("UserProfile")
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Profile")

    <div class="m-4">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>


    @RenderSection("script", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

> This is a View (in which I'll inject different partial views)

```
<div class="container-fluid p-3 shadow-lg border" style="height:80vh;">
    <div id="fund-rule-div">
    </div>
</div>


@section script{

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/ui-js/fund-rule-ui/fund-rule.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("FundRuleIndex")', function (data) {
                $('#fund-rule-div').html(data);
            });


        });
    </script>
}
```

> This is my partial view in which bootstrap-select is not working (not appearing at all)

```
@model Society.Excel.WebApp.ViewModels.FundRuleViewModel


<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="FundRule">Index</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Fund Rule</li>
</ul>


<form method="post" class="form-horizontal " role="form" id="add-fund-rule-form" onsubmit="addUpdateFundRule(event)">

    <h5 class="text-info">Fund Rule</h5>
    <hr class="border-info" />

    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                    <input asp-for="FundRuleModel.IsActive" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="IsActive" checked="checked">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsActive">Is Active?</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <label class="col-form-label"><strong>Rule for :>></strong> </label>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input asp-for="FundRuleModel.IsIncludedInRegularInvoice" id="IsForSystemGeneration_true" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="true" checked>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsForSystemGeneration_true">Regular Invoice</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                <input asp-for="FundRuleModel.IsIncludedInRegularInvoice" id="IsForSystemGeneration_false" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" value="false">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="IsForSystemGeneration_false">Manually Created Invoice</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundRuleName" for="FundRuleName">Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundRuleName" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="FundRuleName" required />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundRuleTypeName" for="FundRuleType">Rule Type <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <select asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundRuleTypeRid" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.FundRuleTypes,"FundRuleTypeRid","FundRuleTypeName"))" class="selectpicker form-control form-control-sm " data-live-search="true" data-size="5" id="FundRuleType" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">Select One</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundCycleName" for="FundCycleName">Fund Cycle<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <select asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundCycleRid" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.FundCycles,"FundCycleRid","FundCycleName"))" class="selectpicker form-control form-control-sm " id="FundCycleName" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">Select One</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.Amount" for="Amount">Amount <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input asp-for="FundRuleModel.Amount" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="Amount" required />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundCalculationTypeName" for="FundCalculationTypeName">Calculation Type <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <select asp-for="FundRuleModel.FundCalculationTypeRid" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CalculationTypes,"FundCalculationTypeRid","FundCalculationTypeName"))" class="selectpicker form-control form-control-sm " id="FundCalculationTypeName" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">Select One</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.FlatCalculationFilterName" for="FlatCalculationFilterRid">Flat Filters<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <select asp-for="FundRuleModel.FlatCalculationFilterRid" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.CalculationFlatFilters,"FlatCalculationFilterRid","FlatCalculationFilterName"))" class="selectpicker form-control form-control-sm " id="FlatCalculationFilterRid" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">Select One</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.ApplicableDate" for="ApplicableDate">Applicable Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="date" asp-for="FundRuleModel.ApplicableDate" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="ApplicableDate" required />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.EndDate" for="EndDate">End Date</label>
                <input type="date" asp-for="FundRuleModel.EndDate" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="EndDate" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FundRuleModel.Narration" for="Narration">Narration</label>
                <textarea asp-for="FundRuleModel.Narration" class="form-control form-control-sm " id="Narration"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success " type="submit">Save</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="fundRuleIndexPage()" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Since you're loading your partial view via jQuery's Get(), your parent view has most likely already loaded. That means, any JS initialization that's needed to run for the select, has already ran before you load the partial view via the Get() method. It won't run again because loading a partial view is not the same as loading a page. So you need to manually execute the JS code responsible for rendering the bootstrap select.

Comment: I had already tried to manually execute the JS in partial view itself but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use partial view in this way, below is a simple demo:

Main View:

```
<div class="container-fluid p-3 shadow-lg border" style="height:80vh;">
    <div id="fund-rule-div">
        <partial name="FundRuleIndex" />
    </div>
</div>


@section script{

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
}
```

Partial View:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

Result:

[image]